# Does a "for ... in" loop in Python increase space complexity?

Tags: python, python-3.x, big-o

Say I had the following function:

```
def findNumVowels(s):
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    numVowels = 0
    for char in s:
        if char in vowels:
            numVowels += 1
    return numVowels

print(findNumVowels("hello world")) # 3
```

Would the `for ... in` loop add to the space complexity of this function by creating a new string for each `char` in `s`, or is this syntactic sugar that abstracts away the fact that we are accessing a specific index of a string?

Comment: no it does not increase space complexity

Comment: Note, indexing into a `str` object *creates a new `str` object anyway*. But all of this is irrelevant to the space complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the loop by itself does not. Consider:

```
for char in some_string:
    print(char)
```

It only requires one extra object of constant size. This is *constant with respect to the size of the string*. So, it doesn't matter if my string is 10 or 1000 characters long, it always requires one extra `str` to loop over it. Therefore, it takes constant space.

Comment: Wouldn't it require `n` extra objects where `n` is the length of the string? The sizes of the strings may be fixed, but with respect to function as a whole, the amount of extra space used would be contingent on the size of the input.

Comment: @KyleU You create new objects but only ever have one at a time. Now, if you accumulated those into a list for example, then it would require O(N) space. With the loop above, the objects are created and destroyed on each iteration.

Comment: this seems to be correct. I'm looking into Python reference counting and garbage collection now and it seems that if there are no references to `char` that it is immediately deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version with list comprehension:

```
def findNumVowels(s):
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    return len([char_literal for char_literal in s if char_literal in vowels])

findNumVowels("Kunal")
```

As you can see Python strings are immutable which means they cannot be changed after they are created. So we are simply indexing the string with the for..in construct, which does not take any extra space complexity.

Comment: `for` loops with `in` are not indexing the iterable. Try a `for` loop and change the temporary variable in the body of the loop.

Comment: Note, *your version here does create O(N) space complexity* because you materialize a list that depends on the size of the string.

Answer (score 0):

First, the answer you cared about is that the for loop actually dose not add to the space complexity. However, if you worked with large arrays, the time complexity of the for loop is very poor. It is recommended to use a vectorized operation instead of multi for loops. For example, `numpy.dot()`, which is very common in machine learning or deep learning.

Comment: Using `numpy` arrays wouldn't help the time or space complexity.